# String almacenado dentro de un arreglo se convierte en undefined en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, ciclos

Tengo unas cadenas de texto almacenadas en un arreglo y quiero utilizarlas para agregar una propiedad *CSS* a una serie de imágenes.

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("post-image");
var link, w, h;
var margenes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

    // Obtener la url de las imágenes externas al DOM
    link = img[i].parentElement.href;

    // Insertar una <img src="link"> en el DOM
    document.getElementById("thread").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<div id='lightbox'><img id='lightbox-img' src='" + link + "'></div>");

    // Utilizar las variables h, w para almacenar el alto y ancho de la imagen
    var lightboxImg = document.getElementById("lightbox-img");
    w = lightboxImg.width;
    h = lightboxImg.height;

    // Construir una cadena de texto con los valores de h y w para mandarla al arreglo
    margenes.push("-" + Math.floor(h / 2) + "px 0px 0px -" + Math.floor(w / 2) + "px");

    // Eliminar la imagen del DOM
    document.getElementById("lightbox").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("lightbox"));

}

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    // Comprobar que imprime la cadena de manera adecuada
    console.log("Prueba " + margenes[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

    // Cuando el puntero está sobre una de las imágenes
    // no son las mismas que el ciclo for anterior
    img[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        link = this.parentElement.href;
        document.getElementById("thread").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<div id='lightbox'><img id='lightbox-img' src='" + link + "'></div>");
        var lightboxImg = document.getElementById("lightbox-img");

        // No funciona
        lightboxImg.style.margin = margenes[i];

        // Imprime "Valor: undefined"
        console.log("Valor: " + margenes[i]);
    }, false);

    img[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        document.getElementById("lightbox").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("lightbox"));
    }, false);

}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Por qué en el tercer ciclo `for` esa cadena aparece como `undefined`?

He intentado lo siguiente, pero tampoco es una solución al problema:

```
String(margenes[i]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Hay algo que debes de tener en cuenta de `JavaScript` y es algo que confunde mucho cuando vienes de otro lenguaje, analiza el siguiente *snippet* y después observa el resultado en la consola:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  setTimeout(function () {
  
    console.log(i);
  
  }, 100);

}
```

La lógica diría que el anterior código debería lanzar en consola los valores que ha ido tomando `i` a lo largo del ciclo pero no es así, en el momento en que se lanza el `setTimeout`, `i` vale `10` (el último valor que tomó antes de que el ciclo terminara) y esto ocurre porque el alcance de una variable en `JavaScript` se limita a la función en la que ha sido declarada en vez de al bloque de código en el que ha sido declarada. Ya comprenderás por qué te da error: estás intentando acceder a un index que no se encuentra dentro de tu `Array`, porque este index tiene como valor el último que tomó la variable de incremento del ciclo `for`.

Para que esto no ocurra, normalmente se usa una [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  (function(i) {
  
    setTimeout(function () {
    
      console.log(i);
    
    }, 100);

  })(i);

}
```

O para que lo entiendas de una manera más legible, puedes crear una función aparte:

```js
function lanzar(i) {

  setTimeout(function() {

    console.log(i);

  }, 100);

}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  lanzar(i);

}
```

Esto se ha solucionado en `ECMAScript 2015` con el uso de [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let). Ya que el ámbito de una variable declarada con `let` (o [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const)) se circunscribe al bloque de código en el que ha sido declarada:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() {

    console.log(i);

  }, 100);

}
```

Puedes usar el método que mejor consideres. Tu código debe seguir una de estas técnicas para que funcione. En el el siguiente *snippet* te pongo un ejemplo usando una `IIFE`:

```js
var margenes = ["cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve"];
var len = margenes.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

  (function(i) {

    var div = document.querySelector("div[data-index='" + i + "']");

    div.addEventListener("click", function() {

      console.log(margenes[i]);

    });

  })(i);

}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-index="0">0</div>
<div class="box" data-index="1">1</div>
<div class="box" data-index="2">2</div>
<div class="box" data-index="3">3</div>
<div class="box" data-index="4">4</div>
<div class="box" data-index="5">5</div>
<div class="box" data-index="6">6</div>
<div class="box" data-index="7">7</div>
<div class="box" data-index="8">8</div>
<div class="box" data-index="9">9</div>
```

Comment: Para que sea más fácil de entender para el OP, la variable de control (i) siempre es 10 porque **se está tomando como *referencia*** debido a su ámbito de alcance (función). Cuando usas `let` o `const` como bien dices, el ámbito se limita a la cabecera de la estructura. Buena respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @GustavoGarcía. Un saludo ;)